# Proof embedding to product space is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Given measurable spaces $(\Omega_1,\Sigma_1), (\Omega_2, \Sigma_2), (\Omega,\Sigma)$ where $\Omega=\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$ and $\Sigma$ is the product $\sigma$ algebra.
Let the embedding function be $e_b:\Omega_1\rightarrow\Omega$ where $e_b(x)=(x,b)$. How do I show that $e_b$ is measurable?

My attempt was:
For any $R\in \Sigma$, we must have $R=A\times B \subseteq\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$ for some $A,B$. However, $e_b^{-1}(A\times B) = \emptyset$ unless $B=\{b\}$. Meaning either $e_b^{-1}(A\times B) =\emptyset$ or $e_b^{-1}(A\times B) =A$. In the case of $e_b^{-1}(A\times B) =A$, why must $A\in\Sigma_1$?

Edit:
Since $\Sigma$ is the smallest sigma algebra. I also tried using structural induction (e.g. prove if $S\in \Sigma$ and $e^{-1}_b(S)\in\Sigma_1$, then $e^{-1}_b(S^c)\in \Sigma_1$), but I'm not sure if induction actually work in this case as I can't construct a well founded relation on $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially $A\in\Sigma_1$ is part of the definition of the product sigma algebra.

However, it should be noted that a general member of $\Sigma$ need not have the form $A\times B\subset \Omega_1\times \Omega_2$.  Rather, $\Sigma$ is *generated* by sets $A\times B$ where $A\in \Sigma_1$ and $B\in\Sigma_2$.  Therefore the inverse image $e_b^{-1}\Sigma$ is *generated* by the sets $e_b^{-1}(A\times B)$, which you can now correctly show are measurable as you have argued.

Comment: But since $\Sigma$ is over $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$, wouldn't that imply $\Sigma\subseteq \mathcal P(\Omega_1\times \Omega_2)$, and so any member of $\Sigma$ is a subset of $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$?

Comment: Yes, but a general subset of $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$ need not have the form $A\times B$.